# In single page application how to reload api without reloading page when new data is entered in VueJs

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I actually have made a single page application for school management where there are multiple records of the student and when data is entered , data are changed in database but doesn't affect other component until I reload the page. 
 **I have used API to fetch the data from database**.How to solve this problem in VueJs.

Comment: Without any code it's impossible to help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to understand how to ask a question so people here can try to help.

Comment: Its simply the code of axios. axios.get("/student/" + this.sectionId).then(result => {
                this.studentData = result.data.data;
                console.log(this.studentData);
            });

Comment: I asked if there is any way to bring the change in database without reloading.

Answer (score 1):

Suppoue you have the students data on `dataStudent:[]` now you entered a new data on same table where from `dataStudent:[]` came, when you enter data to database subbpouse you have data on `formValue:{}` which is object and all the data from formValue added on database now after successfully added you have to push these data to the array,
like: `dataStudent.push(formValue);`

Comment: Can these pushed value be accessed from other component in vuejs while fetching api and change in the same form value in other componenent again be pushed in to another component.

Comment: yes, use $emit and $on properly, its reactive so it will happen.

Comment: I have used eventBus  for emit and on . Is it ok? But that only woks under some events . I want to get updated api without any event occuring. Is it possible?

Comment: here the event is adding new data, also the `created()` is there to help while loading first time and calling api